What is the correct tense of "see": present perfect or past simple?
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) I said to Bill, "I met your uncle in the library ten minutes ago. I haven't seen/didn't see him for about five years."
(1b) I said to Bill, "I met your uncle in the library an hour ago. I haven't seen/didn't see him for about five years."
(1c) I said to uncle, "I met your uncle in the library this morning. I haven't seen/didn't see him for about five years."
My non-native English speaking friends think the present perfect works for (1a) and the simple present works for (1b) and (1c). They think the longer you wait from the meeting time to talk about that, the more likely you have to use the simple past. What is your opinion?

Actually, you need to use the past perfect.

I said to Bill, "I met your uncle in the library ten minutes ago. I hadn't seen him for about five years."

That is, you hadn't seen him for five years, and then you met him in the library.  (Because, obviously, the five years had to be before the ten minutes.)
Where the sentences would be correct would be:

I said to Bill, "I met your uncle in the library ten years ago. I haven't seen him for about five years."

This would mean that you met (as in, first saw) the uncle, and then stopping seeing him after some time -- it has been five years since the last time.
This is a bit awkward as a construction.

I said to Bill, "I met your uncle in the library ten years ago. I didn't see him for about five years."

This is so awkward as to be ambiguous.  Most people would probably mean that you first met him ten years ago and then not for another five years, but it could mean that you didn't see him at some other period.

If the most recent event (seeing the uncle in the library) is in the very recent past (for some value of 'recent', e.g. an hour ago, yesterday, etc) then you can use the present perfect (I haven't seen him for ten years). This is because we can use the present perfect about past actions that are related to, or continue into, the present (loosely defined).
